# Haskell: How to call a recursive function on a modified argument by said recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'd like to implement the lazy reduction of a lambda expression. It should only reduce that expression until it is in WHNF.

The type `LExpr` is defined like this:

```
data LExpr = Var String
            | App LExpr LExpr
            | Lam String LExpr
```

What i did so far:

```
lazy :: LExpr -> LExpr
lazy (Var v) = Var v 
lazy (Lam x e) = Lam x e
lazy (App e1 e2) = 
  case e1 of
    (Lam x e)   -> if (x `elem` bound e1) 
                     then lazy $ subst e2 x e 
                     else App e1 e2
    (App e3 e4) -> App (lazy $ App e3 e4) e2 
    _           -> App e1 e2
```

(`bound` is a List of all Strings that are bound in a expression; `subst` substitutes the string `x` in expression `e` with the expression `e2` and is also doing alpha conversion if necessary)

But this is only reducing one argument. For example if I call `lazy` with `(\x -> x) (\y -> f y) a b`

It will be reduced to: `(\y -> f y) a b`

But I want to have: `f a b`

So basically in the second case-statement I want to call:

```
(App e2 e3) -> lazy $ App (lazy $ App e3 e4) e2
```

But this is not working. How can i call a function on an argument that is modified by said function? Maybe, i can force Haskell to reduce the inner call of `lazy` first?

I also tried to use `fold`:

```
lazy' :: LExpr -> LExpr
lazy' = lfold (\x -> Var x) 
              (\x y -> lazy $ (App x y)) 
              (\x y -> Lam x y)
```

It is working fine for the example above. However, not for this example: `(\z x. (\x. x) z) x`

which will be reduced to: `(\x' -> x)`

But the correct outcome would be: `(\x' -> (\x -> x) x)`

I don't know how to fix this. Maybe someone got an idea and would like to share it with me? Thank you very much in advance.

P.S.: All the functions that I used like "`lfold`" or "`subst`" etc. are from previous homeworks, so I know the implementation is correct. If you'd like to see the  implementation, i can add them.

Comment: IMO, it's easier if you first write a single-step function `step :: LTerm -> Maybe LTerm` which tries to perform a leftmost-outermost step, and returns `Nothing` if the argument is already in normal form. Then you iterate on that as much as needed.

Comment: @chi FWIW, `First` seems like a cute improvement to the `Maybe` approach. `reduce (App e1 e2) = (flip App e2 <$> reduce e1) <> (App e1 <$> reduce e2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I've found the problem.

If i call `(App e3 e4) -> lazy $ App (lazy $ App e3 e4) e2` in the second case-statement,  i only want to do that if `lazy $ App e3 e4` results in a lambda expression. If it is an application of variables (or variable and an expression) it will be called over and over again. So before i call `lazy` on the modified expression, i just need to check whether it is of the form `Lam x e` or not.

Now `lazy` is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the first thing that occurred to me was not to use `case` at all. I can't give it a try, but maybe this idea will help:

```
lazy :: LExpr -> LExpr
lazy (Var v) = Var v 
lazy (Lam x e) = Lam x e
lazy (App e1@(Lam x e) e2) = if (x `elem` bound e1) then lazy $ subst e2 x e else App e1 e2
lazy (App e1@(App _ _) e2) = App (lazy e1) e2 
lazy (App e1 e2@(Var _)) = App e1 e2
lazy (App e1 e2) = App e1 (lazy e2)
```

Comment: I don't think this is reducing an expression into WHNF. Because you never reduce the right side of an application if the left can't be reduced. But that's what happens in the last line of your code.